# How to use Domain name with https instead of localhost for debugging website in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, single-sign-on, okta

I am implementing Single Sign On(using OKTA) on one of our MVC based website where the OKTA takes a Response URL to throw its response back to my code once the user has entered his credentials on OKTA login page

OKTA takes an **HTTPS** based response URL to throw its response.

Things I have done:

1) I have specified a dummy Hostname to my machine using **etc/hosts** file like:

127.0.0.1    www.abc.com

2) Enabled **https://** on www.abc.com on my local machine

3) Specified a route {{controller}}/{{Action}} to receive the response in my code.

4) I have tried specifying Bindings to my local applicationConf file:

```
             <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:58565:localhost" />
                  <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:www.abc.com" />
            </bindings>
```

My VS project configuration looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to receive the response on the local MVC route (hit the breakpoint) when the URL (where OKTA throws response) is like  **https:// www.abc.com/Home/Auth**

**Problem is**  when I write **localhost:58565/Home/Index** or   **http:// www.abc.com/Home/Index** with VS debugging on, it hits the breakpoint but when I type **https:// www.abc.com/Home/Index** (with https) it does not hit the breakpoint in Visual Studio. With https it says 404 Not found.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: In host file instead of mapping loopback address 127.0.0.1 to custom domain you should map it to actual IP of machine to custom domain www.abc.com and then change https bindingInformation with actual ip instead of *.

Comment: @PankajKapare Thanks. You mean getting IP via ipconfig and map it to www.abc.com in hosts file. Tried that it says  : Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

Comment: Did you change https bindinginformation and tried accessing site over https? Are you using local iis or express?

Comment: Binding Info is same as shown in my original post. Do I need to make any changes there? I am using IIS Express as shown in the screenshot above.

Comment: @PankajKapare Somehow, http:// abc.com/Home/Index started working with running VS in Administrator mode, but https:// abc.com/Home/Index still showing 404 not found. What do you think can be the reason.

Answer (score 2):

I got the issue fixed. Posting the solution so that it may be helpful for others.

Steps I followed:

1) Created a Self signed certificate with Powershell(make sure you run Powershell command line with Admin Privileges)

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName www.mydomain.com -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

2) Have correct bindings in my ApplicationConf.host file(this file is now at  Project level now since VS 2015 rather than at IIS level)
like the one below:

```
        <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:58565:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44311:localhost" />
       </bindings>
```

You can add more bindings if using Hostname instead of Localhost. Make sure ports are different for each binding. Also, Https ports should start from 443--ending at 44399.

3) Remove the existing https binding from IIS Default Website and add it back with the certificate created in Step 1 and correct hostname used in Step 1.

Now you should be able to run and debug your code on local machine with self signed SSL.